# BIOS of Dell R410 resets for no good reason

Tags: bios, cmos, dell-poweredge

We run a Dell R410 server. The trouble we are facing is that it does not remember it's BIOS settings. The pain in that is that we need to be physically at the server when it reboots.

Let me list some obserations:

- After a reboot the BIOS settings are lost
- The current time is still available though
- Because the "F1/F2 Prompt on Error" switch is reset to enabled we get a "Fan 4 speed may change depending on system configuration and option card install"  message that prevents booting automatically

What did we try already?

- Changed CMOS battery
- Confirmed that the "AC Power Recovery" jumper is not set

We are in the process of upgrading the BIOS. But the changelog does not list any major failures like this.

What are your observations?

Comment: Have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/138098/dell-poweredge-r410-system-asks-to-press-f1-or-f2
Maybe this will help? It looks Dell-ishly trivial...

Comment: You mean the part about "Well, this really seemed to solve it. For some strange reason we had to change at least one setting and save it in the BIOS to get it update the hardware config - and then the message was gone"? So we should try to update multiple settings before saving the bios?

Comment: If I understand correctly the linked solution they had similar issues and what they did was enter bios, change some (more or less random chosen) setting in there, save it and only after that system updated it's hardware configuration. You don't mention any hardware change in your system, but the symptoms are quite similar. Maybe the very first BIOS reset you had changed something in the config and it persists? BIOS update is a good idea anyway, but sometimes help to restore defaults or clearing CMOS before update. Doesn't say you tried that..

Comment: We did try to change multiple settings after your post. That did not do the trick. In the end the BIOS update DID fix it, although changelog did not mention such a thing. Thanks anyway! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was upgrading the BIOS to the latest version! Although no bugs were mentioned in the changelogs of the updates.

Comment: Good work! Thanks for letting us know. Another one for knowledge base.